# Masonry filter only working once

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, filter, jquery-masonry

I've managed to get multiple filters working using the jQuery Masonry plugin, the only problem is once you've used one filter you can't use another filter until you reload (bear with me I'm still quite new to this). Here's my code:

```
jQuery('#menu1').click(function() {
      var menu = $(this).attr('menuref');
      jQuery('.pics').removeClass('pics').addClass('.hidden').hide().filter("[imageref='" + menu + "']").removeClass('.hidden').addClass('pics').show();
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
});

jQuery('#menu2').click(function() {
      var menu = $(this).attr('menuref');
      jQuery('.pics').removeClass('pics').addClass('.hidden').hide().filter("[imageref='" + menu + "']").removeClass('.hidden').addClass('pics').show();
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
});
```

So there's my 2 filters, here's a template I've uploaded onto my server to to demostrate what I mean: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/testing-testing/
Clicking on 'Filter 1' will successfully filter out the relevant content and reload the masonry plugin as specified, BUT if you then click on 'Filter 2' it merely hides all the content, and vice versa, if you click 'Filter 2' first that will work, then 'Filter 1' won't...until you reload.
Is there any way you can have both the filters working simultaneously?

Comment: Filtering for Masonry is not really supported. Use Isotope by the same developer. See http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/help.html

Comment: @Systembolaget yes I realise that, but is there any way I could put something at the start of each call that would reset the content? i.e. change all the classes back to '.pics' from '.hidden'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would somehow need to implement a re-trigger of Masonry. But [this way of filtering](http://jsfiddle.net/vd4H6/) is just so much simpler and flexible, because it allows for combination filters also.

```
$(function() {

var $container = $('#container');

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: your least common divisor in pixels here
    }
});

$('#filters').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var selector = $(this).data('filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
});

});
```

UPDATE: see this two years old [sort of a "hack" by the developer](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/40) regarding a user who also needed to re-layout after hiding/showing items (blog posts). His solution is to apply masonry only to visible elements.

Comment: yes, I do plan on using the isotope plugin further down the line, but as I'm a bit pushed for time I'm just trying to get this filter working to save me changing the rest of my code. Is there anyway to re-trigger the masonry? Even changing the class back from '.hidden' to '.pics' doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: This is using Isotope, not Masonry.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I do plan on using the isotope plugin further down the line, but as I'm a bit pushed for time I'm just trying to get this filter working to save me changing the rest of my code. Is there anyway to re-trigger the masonry? Even changing the class back from '.hidden' to '.pics' doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

```
jQuery('#menu1').click(function() {
      var menu = $(this).attr('menuref');
      jQuery('.pics').removeClass('pics').addClass('.hidden').hide().filter("[imageref='" + menu + "']").removeClass('.hidden').addClass('pics').show();
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
});

jQuery('#menu2').click(function() {
      var menu = $(this).attr('menuref');
      jQuery('.pics').removeClass('pics').addClass('.hidden').hide().filter("[imageref='" + menu + "']").removeClass('.hidden').addClass('pics').show();
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
});
```

Both are my filters are working on their own, but when one is used after the other it just hides all the '.pics' content, can't seem to figure it out at all.